# Create UISwipeGestureRecognizer on top of status bar

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, statusbar, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I'm building a very feature-packed app at the moment and I want to implement a kind of 'go back' action triggered by a gesture recognizer. As the rest of the screen is already used the only place left is the status bar.

So the question is, is it even possible and if so how?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can place a transparent `UIWindow` above the status bar, and then give that `UIWindow` a `UISwipeGestureRecognizer`.

See [MTStatusBarOverlay](https://github.com/myell0w/MTStatusBarOverlay) on how to add a `UIWindow` over the status bar.

Specifically, create a `UIWindow` like so:

```
UIWindow *window = [[UIWindow alloc] init];
window.frame = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarFrame];
window.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelStatusBar + 1.0f;
[window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

then add your `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` to it.

If this doesn't work immediately, you may have to set the `backgroundColor` property to be non-clear. Clear `UIViews` pass through touches (although I believe they should still work with `UIGestureRecognizers`.

Comment: It's also worth noting that you may run into problems with your keyboard not entering text if you don't call `resignKeyWindow` on the overlay first.

Answer (score 0):

There is unfortunately no way to detect a swipe on the Status Bar, as it's a component controlled entirely by the operating system itself (similarly to the Multitasking Tray or Notification Center), and isn't under the jurisdiction of an app.

You may be able to throw something together on a jailbroken device, but for a standard iPhone or iPad, there is no (and likely will never be) Public API for interacting with the Status Bar.